# Alternative for custom info window for flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am new to Flutter.
I want to implement a feature in my project where if a person taps on the map it will get the exact address of it which will also be displayed on the map itself.

I am using custom info window for it but when I'm trying to run it on web, it's not working.

I did some research and I came to know that custom info window is not supported by the flutter web.
Is there any alternative I can use for flutter web application.